# Html file not showing in select wizard in Spring tool suite

Tags: java, spring

For creating a html file in spring tool suits html file is not available in select wizard.

Comment: This question is very vague, try adding steps you followed, screenshots and everything relatable.

Answer (score 13):

You must go to Eclipse marketplace:
**Help->Eclipse Marketplace**

There type in the find box: **Thymeleaf** and enter to search.
When the result appers install it

[Ecplise Marketplace - Thymeleaf plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDDbw.png)

Restart the STS, and now you can add a Html template by the wizard, under:
**New file -> Other -> HTML File**

Comment: It works :) Thank you

Comment: This option asked me to install non secure software (non signed). That's why I have chosen the @efren-robles solution...

Comment: Works fine for me but, you must to start STS as administrator

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I found the solution by reading this information:

https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/622

Basically, you need to go to the menu:

```
Help
 ->Install New Software
```

In the "Work with:", select something like this:

"Spring Tool Suite 4 - [https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/latest"](https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/latest%22)

In the filter text, type "HTML"

And then select:

```
-> Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
    -> Eclipse Web Developer Tools
    -> Wild Web Developer components
```

Install them and restart the Spring Tool Suite

That fixed my issue, I hope that it be helpful for you.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. It perfectly works for me. I can have HTML, JSP, XML, and all files extension inside Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: Was the best solution for me, thanks Efren!!!

Answer (score 0):

STS 4 --> File ---> New --> Other and search "html". By default, when you install the first time the IDE STS version 4,  it doesnt show anything.

After I installed plugin http://www.thymeleaf.org/eclipse-plugin-update-site from Spring tool suite IDE and finnaly i can now new file html extension from wizard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2by.png)

Comment: please update your answer with more specifics - understand the questions is vague, but not sure how this answer helps solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

go to help in that we have to select eclipse marketplace and install eclipse Web developer tools, now we can find the html file in the wizard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfjMC.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DXxr.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).